# how to pass data to children ? reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Here the simple code I am using to pass through children with a verification of authentication:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const [BodyContent, setBodyContent] = useState("...");
  const [User, setUser] = useState({});
  const getBodyContent = async ({ children }) => {
    const auth = await getInLocalStorage("auth");
    if (auth !== "true") {
      window.location.href = "/";
    } else {
      setBodyContent(children);
      const user = await read("/auth/" + (await getInLocalStorage("userId")));
      if (user.status === 200) {
        setUser(user.message);
      }
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getBodyContent({ children });
  }, [children]);

  return <Layout user={User}>{BodyContent}</Layout>;
}
```

How can i add the information of which user is it ? Which role he has ?

Comment: I find your question a bit confusing, but if you need to pass information down to your children components, you simply need to pass them as `props`

Comment: I have User state with my user but the children doesnt have the User information, i nee to pass the children and add to it User data

Comment: @LastryCoding children are supposed to be react components, not data, i don't think it's possible to store them in a useState and re render them as a component.